# For an online questionnaire, how to design a database for keeping track of all users attempts?

Tags: database-design

We have a web app where users can take online exams.

Exam admin will create a questionnaire. A questionnaire can have many Questions. Each question is a multiple choice question (MCQ).

Lets say an admin creates a questionnaire with 10 questions. Users attempt those questions. Now, unlike real exams users can attempt single questionnaire multiple times. And we have to keep track of his all attempts.

e.g.

```
    User_id     Questionnaire_id    question_id answer  attempt_date    attempt_no
1       1           1       a   1 June 2013 1
1       1           2       b   1 June 2013 1

1       1           1       c   2 June 2013 2
1       1           2       d   2 June 2013 2
```

Now it can also happen that  after user has attempted same questionnare twice, admin can delete a question from same questionnaire, but users attempt history should still have reference to that so that user can see his that question in his attempt history in spite of admin deleting that question.

If user now attempts this changed questionnaire he should see only 1 question.

```
    User_id     Questionnaire_id    question_id answer  attempt_date    attempt_no
1       1           1       a   3 June 2013 3
```

Also, after this user modified some part of question, users attempt history should show question before modification while any new attempt should show modified question.

How do we manage this at the database level?

My first gut feeling was that,

For deletes, do not do physical delete, just make a question inactive so that history can still keep track of users attempt.

For modifications, create versions for questions and each new attempt refres to latest version of each question and history keeping reference to version of question at attempt time.

Comment: No point deleting data that could be useful in the future

Answer (score 3):

*(Sorry, I used "exam" instead of "questionnaire" - the latter is just too unwieldy a name for my diagram.)*

Yes, you'd have to do some form of versioning. Versioning objects in isolation is easy enough, but versioning *links* between objects can get complicated in a hurry. To keep it (relatively) simple, you could do something like this:

[image]

This forms a hierarchy, that can be versioned in a bottom-up fashion in response to changes:

- Modification of answer's text, addition or removal of an answer, or modification of question's text is considered a modification of the question.
- Which, along with addition or deletion of questions, is considered a modification of the exam.
- Which is done by creating a new exam version and copying the complete tree under the old exam version while applying the appropriate changes.

This "hierarchical" approach to versioning, i.e. creating a new version of the whole tree in response to modification of any tree node, can be a bit wasteful, but is fairly straightforward to reason about and implement.

An alternative would be to explicitly version child objects **and links**, and then carefully query so only the specific "snapshot in time" is retrieved. This would obviously require a significantly different database schema...

---

Incidentally to above, you'll notice a prodigious use of identifying relationships and the resulting composite primary keys. This is necessary for correctly modelling the diamond-shaped dependency that bottoms at USER_ANSWER, so the user cannot provide an answer that doesn't belong to the exam.

QUESTION.ANSWER_NO helps identify the correct answer (this assumes [MATCH SIMPLE](http://wiki.burnsoft.net/KB58.ashx) foreign keys - also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16360641/533120)).

ATTEMPT.TIMESTAMP is the date/time at which the user started her attempt. Together with the times at which individual answers were given, the complete "timeline" can be recreated. The length of exam is the period between attempt start and the last answer.

USER_ANSWER.ANSWER_NO is kept **outside** the primary key, so no two different answers can be provided to the same question on the same attempt.

The DELETED flag exists in the exam version, not the exam itself, so if you undelete the exam there will be a historical record of that. You can even delete and undelete the same exam multiple times.

Comment: "survey" is an acceptable shorter alias for "questionnaire".  "Exam" has a much different connotation to it.

Comment: +1: Nice work.  Though I might want to add an [ExamVersion_to_Question] many-to-many mapping table between [Exam_Version] and [Question], that way the same question could appear on more than one Exam_Version.  (Of course you'd also have to put the Question_No column in that table as well)

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thanks for proposing "survey" - English is not my native language and I obviously missed the mark here a little. As for the `ExamVersion_to_Question` it really depends on requirements, but importantly, this would stop being a tree (and remain just [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)), which would warrant the alternative strategy for dealing with versioning (as I shortly mentioned in my answer).